# unwanted horizontal scroll bar in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, fluid-layout

http://www.twofivefivefive.com/asctest/

I am helping a friend with this site, and it is a fluid, % based design (which I have no experience working with).

For some reason, I am getting a horizontal scroll bar, that scrolls into blank space on the right side. I haven't the faintest clue what is causing the page to be wider than it should be, I've triple checked the code and everything seems to be in order; I am getting desperate!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, on large monitors, the "About | Another Page" links at the top (div#topNav) is placed at the very top-right of the large white box (div#container) if there is room on the right. (If you don't see this, just zoom out on your browser to pretend you have a bigger monitor.) I think this is because the previous node (div#topTitle) has "float: left" set. If you don't set "float: left" on div#topTitle and change its margin-top to padding-top, this should fix the problem. But it might affect other items on the page (not very likely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all inside the `<div id="header">`. The `<div id="topTitle">` and the `<div id="topNav">` both have the CSS "position" property set to "relative" and then the "left" property to give it an offset from the left side of the page. However, the element maintains its same width (100%) and is pushed off to the right side.

If you set "margin-left" instead of "left", the elements will have a left margin but will not push off towards the right because the "left" is still at the left edge of the container (so div#topTitle should have `margin-left: 270px;` set and not have the "left" property set and div#topNav should have `margin-left: 281px;` set (261px "migrated" from the "left" property and an extra 20px that was already set as margin-left) with no "left" property.